# iOS 7 app icon sizes not being recognized

Tags: icons, app-store, ios7

I've tried this about nine different ways tonight (and read through all the SO responses to similar issues, all of which have a straightforward similar resolution that doesn't seem to be working for me).

I'm getting this response from Apple after submission:

> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "[App Name]". Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to correct the following issues in your next delivery:
>
> **Missing recommended icon file** - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png format.
>
> **Missing recommended icon file** - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '76x76' pixels, in .png format.
>
> **Missing recommended icon file** - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '152x152' pixels, in .png format.

Now, normally the advice is to make sure those app icon sizes are included, obviously, but also in the Info.plist.

The problem is that I've verified that they're in both — I have Icon-76.png, Icon-120.png, and Icon-152.png in the app bundle along with all the other pre-iOS-7 icons, and Info.plist includes, under "Icon files", "Icon-76.png", "Icon-120.png", and "Icon-152.png" along with all the other icon filenames.

I've cleaned, deleted any other developer-rejected archives, checked to make sure the archive from the Organizer has the icons and updated Info.plist, and tried rejecting and resubmitting several times, always receiving the missing-icons email upon the otherwise successful submission.

Has anyone run into this sort of thing, and/or have a possible solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Could it maybe be so that you have added the icons to the asset catalog but not set the asset catalog to be used, or vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

If you use asset catalogues, could it be, that the asset catalog is not part of your build target? Check it by clicking on the catalogue in the project explorer and inspecting the targets in the inspector window.